# How to contain the width of an element so it does not overflow the body, but IS visible?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to have an element with a greater width then the body, but not cause horizontal scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/hYRGT/

This hopefully demonstrates my problem somewhat.
The #header contains the #imghead and is set to 960px width.

What I want is the browser to 'think' the page is 960px wide.
Because #imghead is more wide then #header and positioned relative so it's in the center.

I'm not able to use a background-image because #imghead is going to be replaced by a flash component.

I'm also not able to use overflow:hidden because I DO want the element to show outside the 960px. I just don't want it to cause h-scrolling.

I do not want to disable h-scrolling altogether, I'd really love a CSS solution. But if javascript is the only way of dealing with this, I guess it would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got what I wanted:
http://jsfiddle.net/hYRGT/3/

Just in case jsfiddle would be down:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<title>WEBSITE title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="imghead"><img src="/img.jpg" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="index">
        <div id="container">SOME CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/*RESET*/
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,dd,dl,dt,li,ol,ul,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-family:inherit;font-weight:inherit;font-style:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:baseline}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
a img,:link img,:visited img{border:0}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal}
ol,ul{list-style:none}
caption,th{text-align:left}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal}
q:before,q:after{content:''}
abbr,acronym{border:0}
img{display:block}
a{color:inherit}

/*STYLES*/
html, body{
height:100%}
body{
background:#000;
text-align:center;
overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto}

#wrapper{
    z-index:12;
    position:relative;
    height:auto!important;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#0f0;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:visible}
#container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#00f}

#header{
    z-index:50;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:0px;
    background:#f00}
#imghead{
    width:1100px;
    position:relative;
    left:-70px;
    background:#ff0}
```

The content overlaps the header by design,
I hope this helps someone.

1 limitation is that the header does not horizontally scroll, 
but in my design that is not necessary.

Tested in FF3, IE8, S4 and C5

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just absolutely position it relative to the body, 50% from the left and then on the inner element do a negative left margin of half the total width of the element itself which would center it?

Comment: That would be another way to center it, and it works at that, but it still causes scrolling as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/DnyDd/